# Python access denied to mmap file created by local system

Tags: python, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to access a memory mapped file created by SYSTEM from another user.
I'm running a windows service using a python frozen exe. the service is run as local SYSTEM. In the service I create a mmap file (using python mmap module)
I later create another process under a logged in user, and try to access the mmap file, but get an

> WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

I was able to simplify the problem to the following:

Run python as local system using

```
PsExec.exe -i -s -d python
```

create a memory mapped file -

```
mmap_file = mmap.mmap(-1, 1024, tagname='Global\\test', access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
```

Now, open a python console from the user cmd (just run python)
and try to open the same mmap file using

```
mmap_file = mmap.mmap(-1, 1024, tagname='Global\\test', access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
```

again, the same

> WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

The code works if I just run it from two different python consoles running as the same user.

How can I change the permissions on the mmap file so it can be accessed by users other than SYSTEM?

Using python 2.7.10 Windows 7

The actual code I'm using in the service to run the process

```
appName = 'script.exe'
commandLine = 'script.exe'
session_id = 1 
security_token = win32ts.WTSQueryUserToken(session_id)
processAttributes = None
threadAttributes = None
bInheritHandles = 0
dwCreationFlags = win32process.DETACHED_PROCESS 
newEnvironment = None 
currentDirectory = None
startupinfo = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.lpDesktop = "winsta0\default"
process = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(security_token, appName , commandLine , processAttributes , threadAttributes , bInheritHandles , dwCreationFlags , newEnvironment , currentDirectory , startupinfo )
```

Comment: It's unnecessary to do `access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE`, it's default on Windows. From python using Windows you can't control the access of mapping (different than unix). In your simplified problem description, provide your python syntax for when you open the files for reading/writing, it matters.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what solution are you offering to the problem?

Comment: I'm asking for you to provide the code you used to open the file for each mmap (in the simplified approach). You can have permission issues if you don't open the files correctly. For instance, you need to open the file in read/write mode since that's the mode it was mapped in. And as I explained in my first post, this is because you can't control the access of mapping in Windows.

Comment: I used the same code as above, meaning with ACCESS_WRITE. I have also tried all other possible combinations after your comment ( ACCESS_WRITE, ACCESS_READ, ACCESS_WRITE | ACCESS_READ. both for creating and for reading the mmap. All resulted in the same access error

Comment: ... I mean when you created and then opened the mmap, like: `with open(foo, 'r+b') as f`

Comment: I didn't use an actual file with "open". I used an anonymous memory, by sending -1 to the mmap constructor.

Comment: In case this helps anyone, I didn't really manage to solve this permissions problem. What I ended up doing to overcome this was whenever I needed to read the mmap from a user, i duplicated the SYSTEM user token, and launched that python code as a SYSTEM user... not the best solution but it worked